# Results with a flavor “every automorphism of automorphisms is inner”

Tags: big-list, gm.general-mathematics

It seems that there are a number of results which take more or less the following form: let $X$ be some (specific) kind of structure, let $Y$ be the group of automorphisms of $X$ or perhaps ring of endomorphisms something of the sort, and consider an automorphism of $Y$: then it comes from an automorphism of $X$, i.e., it is inner.

Here are some examples which come to my mind:

- $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak{S}_n) = \mathfrak{S}_n$ for $n\neq 6$ (here $X$ is a finite set with $n$ elements and $Y$ is $\mathfrak{S}_n$).
- The Skolem-Noether theorem that automorphisms of the ring of linear endomorphisms of $k^n$ (with $k$ a field) are inner.
- The [Dyer-Formanek theorem](https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s2-11.2.181) about the automorphism group of the automorphism group of the free group with rank $n$ (which I was “reminded” of by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464109/is-every-automorphism-of-mathrmautf-2-induced-by-conjugation-inside-m)).
- We might even argue that the Yoneda lemma has a similar flavor (as it tells us that a homomorphism of homomorphism functors comes from a homomorphism of the underlying category).

I'm sure there are many more, so I think it might be interesting to make a big-list out of them.

Comment: I suppose this is some kind of higher-order generalization: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5635/does-declaremathoperator-autaut-aut-aut-dots-autg-dots-stabilize  In particular, see the answer describing how your question is true for $X$ any simple group (which sounds similar to the full statement of Skolem-Noether)

Comment: Every automorphism of the monoid of all mappings on a set is given by conjugation by a permutation.  This result probably goes back to Schreier and has been rediscovered many times.

Answer (score 5):

I think there is such a result for the group of diffeomorphisms of a manifold: under some assumptions any iso between Diffeo (M) and Diffeo (N) comes from a diffeo between M and N.

(The assumptions are weak. Compactness maybe, certainly connectedness or pure positive-dimensionality to avoid the set with six elements).

Comment: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/ergodic-theory-and-dynamical-systems/article/isomorphisms-between-diffeomorphism-groups/BE5563E03AD7DA6A94D08F92CFA4AF90

Comment: When one looks at the article I posted a link to above, one sees that the only assumptions are paracompactness and connectedness. So, almost nothing.

Comment: Name of the reference: [Filipkiewicz  - Isomorphisms between diffeomorphism groups](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0143385700001486).  But why tuck these clarifications away in a comment, rather than editing it into your answer?

Comment: Oh sorry you are right. I behaved like if I were on X rather than on MO. This is too late for editing now, unfortunately.